# React Native : Trying to fetch API and add to Flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, api

trying to fethch data and insert to Flatlist , can someone show my mistake, tried almost everything, Tried to make like in `Official Docs`, but didnt help:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://app.sm117.ru/api/v1/contract/news/'),{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}}

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      }, []);
  
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.id}, {item.title}</Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Why my code does not work???

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure the file you are trying to get is JSON file

Comment: but what is it then do u know, cause it  is my like testing exam to get hire job , i did all this stuff but couldnt fetch it((

Comment: and hint was like this :  [
 {
 "id": 0,
 "date": "string",
 "title": "string",
 "body": "string"
 },
 ...
]

Comment: Im sure that the return for the API doesnt contain movies. First console log the return of the API and then find the top most item ( in which you will have {"id": 0, ....} and replace movies with it

Answer (score 0):

At least the last parentheses is missing after

```
headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}}
```

There should be a “)” to close the “fetch” call before “then”

Comment: headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}} )  you mean like this? Giving error

Comment: @Feliks_JS the .then has to be right after the ) parentheses, or right in the next line. Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Just white screen no any errors, maybe it is because of SetData(Json.movies), but i dont know how to call my Json cause it doesnt have any Title , i mean like If it was movies = [f.....], i could do it, but here i dont have , what can i add there